# Percorrer listas de tamanhos diferentes

Tags: python

Estou percorrendo duas listas e realizando uma operação, mas quando a lista menor acaba o for para e a operação não é 100% concluida. Como faço para que quando a menor lista acabar ela retorne para o primeiro elemento e que assim seja até a lista maior acabar?

```
m = []
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
for e, i in zip(x, y):
   f = e
   g = i
   f = f + g
   m.append(f)
```

Comment: uma dica para você conseguir resolver isso é fazer o  `for` para a lista maior e na menor você fazer um `if` verificando se ela já acabou ou não

Answer (score 3):

> Como faço para que quando a menor lista acabar ela retorne para o primeiro elemento e que assim seja até a lista maior acabar?

Se você precisa que os elementos de `x` fiquem cíclicos até que toda a lista `y` seja percorrida, basta você utilizar a função `itertools.cycle`:

```py
from itertools import cycle

x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6,7,8,9]

for a, b in zip(cycle(x), y):
  print(a, b)
```

Isso produzirá a saída:

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
1 7
2 8
3 9
```

Perceba que para os elementos 7, 8 e 9 de `y` os valores de `x` foram se repetindo a partir do início.

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Claro que existem outras formas de fazer isso mas tentei manter a estrutura do seu código.
Neste caso utilizei o `zip_longest` do pacote `itertools` para percorrer as listas de acordo do tamanho da maior lista, veja que os valores faltantes da primeira lista são preenchidos com valores `None`

```
import itertools
​
m = []
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
​
for e, i in itertools.zip_longest(x, y, fillvalue = None):
    if e != None: 
        f = e
        g = i
        f = f + g
    else :
        f = i
    m.append(f)
​
```

Output:

```
print(m)
[5, 7, 9, 7, 8, 9]
```

Caso queira que a menor lista se repita você pode utilizar o `cycle` do mesmo pacote `itertools`

```
import itertools

m = []
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6,7,8,9]

for e, i in zip(itertools.cycle(x), y):
    f = e
    g = i
    f = f + g
    m.append(f)
print(m)
```

Output:

```
[5, 7, 9, 8, 10, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use itertools `cycle`.
Assumindo que você saiba que x é a lista menor e usando compreensao de lista em uma linha apenas:

```
from itertools import cycle


x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
m = [a + b for a, b in zip(cycle(x), y)]
print(m)
```

Comment: funcionou aquii, valeeu

Answer (score 0):

Assim, para cada elemento da lista X, ele percorrerá toda a lista Y antes de avançar para o próximo elemento da lista X.

```
m = []
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
for e in x:
   for i in y:
      f = e
      g = i
      f = f + g
      m.append(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que percebi, você está querendo percorrer as duas listas de forma simultânea e **somar** os valores correspondentes das duas lista, índice por índice. Para isso você deve perceber que existe três casos distintos para resolver, que são:

1. Caso 1: As duas listas tem o mesmo tamanho;
2. Caso 2: A primeira lista tem menor tamanho;
3. Caso 3: A primeira lista tem maior tamanho;

Para se resolver esta questão de forma bem abrangente, isto é, que possa englobar os três casos supracitados, poderemos implementar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

m = []
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

if len(x) < len(y):
    for e, i in zip_longest(x, y, fillvalue=None):
        if e is not None:
            f = e
            g = i
            h = f + g
        else:
            h = i
        m.append(h)
elif len(x) == len(y):
    for e, i in zip(x, y):
        h = e + i
        m.append(h)
else:
    for e, i in zip_longest(y, x, fillvalue=None):
        if e is not None:
            f = e
            g = i
            h = f + g
        else:
            h = i
        m.append(h)

print(m)
```

Observe que o bloco **if** verifica se o tamanho da lista `x` é **menor** que o tamanho da lista `y` e, se for, estas duas listas serão percorridas com o auxílio do método `zip_longest` completando os elementos faltantes da lista `x` com o valor `None`. Em seguida soma cada correspondência de elementos índice a índice, armazenando-os na lista `m` e, em seguida, exibe a lista `m`.

Já o bloco **elif** verifica se o tamanho da lista `x` é **igual** ao tamanho da lista `y` e, se for, estas duas lista serão percorridas com o auxílio da função `zip`, somando cada correspondência de elementos índice a índice, armazenando-os na lista `m` e, em seguida, exibi a lista `m`.

E por último temos o bloco **else**. Este bloco será executado caso o tamanho da lista `x` seja **maior** que o tamanho da lista `y`. Neste caso as duas listas são percorridas com o auxílio do método `zip_longest` completando os elementos faltantes da lista `y` com o valor `None`. Em seguida soma cada correspondência de elementos índice a índice, armazena-os na lista `m` e, em seguida, exibe a lista `m`.

Agora, caso você precise generalizar este problema para **quaisquer duas listas**, você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

x = list(map(int, input('Digite os valores da lista "X": ').split()))
y = list(map(int, input('Digite os valores da lista "Y": ').split()))

m = []

if len(x) < len(y):
    for e, i in zip_longest(x, y, fillvalue=None):
        if e is not None:
            f = e
            g = i
            h = f + g
        else:
            h = i
        m.append(h)
elif len(x) == len(y):
    for e, i in zip(x, y):
        h = e + i
        m.append(h)
else:
    for e, i in zip_longest(y, x, fillvalue=None):
        if e is not None:
            f = e
            g = i
            h = f + g
        else:
            h = i
        m.append(h)

print(m)
```

Neste segundo algoritmo, quando aparecer a seguinte frase `Digite os valores da lista "X":` , você deve digitar **todos** os elementos da lista `X`, na mesma linha, separados por um só espaço e, em seguida, pressionar `enter`. E, quando aparecer a outra frase `Digite os valores da lista "Y":` , você deve digitar **todos** os elementos da lista `Y`, na mesma linha, separados por um só espaço e, em seguida, pressionar `enter`.

A partir desse momento o algoritmo realizará o resto das operações.